Stuck on fetch front-end
Ive written a small webpage and when i send my email to the back end it sends it
font-end
step 1
async function userSend()
    {
        let input=document.getElementById("email").value;//save this as an object
        //window.alert(input);
        //loading();
        console.log("here3");
        const res=await fetch(userD1,
        {
            method:"POST",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"

            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
            Email:input
            })

        });
    }

I call the function when a user clicks a button thats linked to createAccount()
step2
async function createAccount()
{
        
await userSend();//will tell you its sent
let user=await userCheck();
}

It goes to the server where i collect it
step3
app.post("/collectEmail",(req,res)=>
    {
        emailC=req.body;
        found=find1(emailC);
        console.log(emailC.Email+" Is collected from the front-end");
    })

I find the data on mongo db and send it back.
My front end is still stuck on step one. Im not sure what the problem is
The mongo connection code and findOne() works and displays outputs on my sever console.
I expect to send the data from the front to the back it gets checked and then sent back to the front where i display if the account exists or not.
Not sure what ive done wrong here
I have a lot of setInteval and Timeouts running on my front-end. If i have not cleared one could it stall my async functions when trying to receive data from the server.

"Stuck" in what way?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.

My front-end does not recieve any data from the back-end. Its stuck on the post/fetch

The back-end code doesn't appear to ever send data (or any response at all) to the front-end.  Did you simply forget that step?  Possibly just a typo or oversight when referencing code from whatever tutorials or examples you're using?

@David hello, its working now. I might be wrong but what I've noticed is that the reason why the post promise hadn't resolved is because it need to have the res receive on the front-end. It all works I send and receive data. The only issue i have not after a certain amount of time my server cuts out and i get a mongo connection issue. I have a boolean switch passed into a function when ever i need to open mongo and when i close it i just set the switch to false. Not sure how exactly mongo communicates with node JS  and what conditions they are using. Will figure it out

I think you're missing the return of the response from the backend.
Here's some updated code with additional error handling:
 // Frontend (Client-side)
    async function userSend() {
        try {
            const input = document.getElementById("email").value;
            
            // Validate email before sending
            if (!input || !input.includes('@')) {
                throw new Error('Invalid email address');
            }
    
            const res = await fetch('/collectEmail', { 
                method: "POST", 
                headers: { 
                    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
                }, 
                body: JSON.stringify({ Email: input }) 
            });
    
            // Check if response is successful
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error('Server response was not ok');
            }
    
            const data = await res.json(); // Parse the response
            
            // Handle the result
            if (data.exists) {
                // Account already exists
                displayMessage('Account already exists');
            } else {
                // Account can be created
                displayMessage('Account can be created');
            }
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            displayMessage(error.message);
        }
    }
    
    function displayMessage(message) {
        const messageElement = document.getElementById('message');
        messageElement.textContent = message;
    }
    
    // Backend (Server-side, Express with MongoDB)
    app.post("/collectEmail", async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const emailC = req.body;
            const found = await find1(emailC.Email);
            
            // Send back a clear response
            res.json({ 
                exists: !!found,  // Convert to boolean
                message: found ? 'Account exists' : 'Account available'
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Server error:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ 
                exists: false, 
                message: 'Server error occurred' 
            });
        }
    });
    
    // Improved find1 function (assuming mongoose)
    async function find1(email) {
        try {
            return await User.findOne({ email: email });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Database lookup error:', error);
            throw error;
        }
    }


Server error: MongoInvalidArgumentError: Query filter must be a plain object or ObjectId

I think i made a stupid mistake. The post can both send and recieve data?

yeah, thanks your answer helped solve my question. Thanks

Hey @joshua,
your backend endpoint /collectEmail, yes has the ability to receive data & send back data (a confirmation message for success, failure and even the updated data itself).
This is super important because if there's no message sent back, the rest of the frontend code will stall and not move forward.
If you want to skip this, you can avoid having the async/await words in front of the function.
Your frontend code (webpage) - yes, it can send data to the backend and also receive it. Feel free to ask any more questions.

you've been a great help. I did not know that. I've done a lot of java code so i write all my validations from scratch. Im basically just looking to send single  data types for switches. I must say Express is definatly confusing to begin with. I will make use of your help in the near future

I would like to write some modules for Node JS as well. Once I have a solid understanding. Basically string handlers for sign up forms, validation modules. Would be interesting to do.

I do actually have another question to ask. I have a button that creates element onclick. But on the HTML console once ive created the elements it displays its self in the 